# MySQL Reduce data to be 64 Chars wide?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to reduce the size of some data in a column in MySQL which has some lengths >64 and a lot <64.

I basically only want to get `left(columnID, 64)` so that any data >64 chars is now 64 chars and others are preserved ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl
   SET columnID = LEFT(columnID, 64)
 WHERE LENGTH(columnID) > 64
```

Comment: @Tom: as long as you like the answer - you check it with checkmark (under the downvote arrow). That is how SO works ;-)

Comment: sure :) i had to wait the required "10 mins" :) thanks again!

Comment: @Tom: ok ;-) Forgot about that limit ;-)